# where html pages from vaadin flow IFrame are saved

Tags: tomcat, iframe, vaadin-flow

I set an Iframe object with an html page and loaded into the meta-inf/resources/icons/webpages. It loads ok, but when I try to change the content of this web page, by going in its folder, it does not change in browser. I tried to reopen the browser or ide(sts) but the page remains the initial.

```
IFrame iFrame = new IFrame("webpages/my-erp.html");
```

any advise?

Comment: Could you please clarify? You said you load `meta-inf/resources/icons/webpages`, but then say the "initial" is `webpages/my-erp.html`.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. I had to clear the cache of the browser.